# Moving UIButton position, animated

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibutton

I have a UIButton, which when it's pressed I want to move the position of it.

I've managed to do this by this code:

```
ans2.frame = CGRectOffset(ans2.frame, 0, 20);
```

However this just moves the button instantly.

I've also tried just moving it by doing ++ to the position until the new one is reached, however this makes it look like the "animation" lags.

Would it be possible to move the button with a smooth animation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIKit provides several ways to perform animations. The simplest way in your case would be this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
   ans2.frame = CGRectOffset(ans2.frame, 0, 20);
}];
```

However, there are plenty of other possibilities to animate. Checkout [Apple's Animation Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html)

Comment: Better to animate a change to the view's center property. The frame property is only valid if you haven't changed the view's transform. Changing the center property always works correctly.

Comment: And if you're using AutoLayout then you should really connect constraints to the view as outlets and animate changes to those constraints.