# how to change position of button with Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

change position when it is pressed.
UIButton * button = sender;

```
CGPoint position = button.frame.origin;
[UIButton setAnimationDuration:1.0];

CGSize size = button.frame.size;
button.frame = CGRectMake(position.x + 80,position.y,size.width,size.height);
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622418-animate

Comment: did you get your answer?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
   btn.frame = CGRectOffset(btn.frame, 0, 20);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

For animating the position of `UIButton` with duration 1.0 seconds

```
        CGPoint position = button.frame.origin;
        CGSize size = button.frame.size;

        -(IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender {
               [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
                    button.frame = CGRectMake(position.x+80,position.y,size.width,size.height);
                }];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(position.x + 80,position.y,size.width,size.height); // initial frame

 [UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^{
             button.frame = CGRectMake(position.x + 80,position.y,size.width,size.height); // new frame frame

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Animation block of `UIView` class ...

whatever you change  the frame inside this block , the canvas fill the frame in between 
 Set the Start frame

`button.frame= yourInitialFrame;`

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
  // set the End Frame here
                 button.frame = CGRectMake(position.x + 
             80,position.y,size.width,size.height); // new frame frame

            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            }];
```

also see this [see this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html) for more help

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
  // set the End Frame here
                 button.frame = CGRectMake(position.x + 
             80,position.y,size.width,size.height); // new frame frame

            } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(IBAction)ButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *aBtnRef = sender;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        aBtnRef.frame = CGRectMake(aBtnRef.frame.origin.x + 50,aBtnRef.frame.origin.y, aBtnRef.frame.size.width, aBtnRef.frame.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}
```

For More Info :

[Animation : How to make UIbutton move from right to left when view is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671966/animation-how-to-make-uibutton-move-from-right-to-left-when-view-is-loaded)

[Moving UIButton position, animated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918843/moving-uibutton-position-animated)

Answer (score 0):

```
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        CGRect rect = button.frame;
        rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x + 80;
        button.frame = rect;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.